# Age of a process in the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, task, android-kernel

Given the `struct task_struct` to work with.  What's the best way to determine how old a process is?

The `task_struct` is used to hold specific pointers to it's next youngest sibling, and oldest child.  That no longer seems to be available in some kernel versions.

I'm specifically using the Android goldfish kernel. I've been trying to learn how to use the `list_head` structure to iterate over processes, but I can't seem to figure out how to determine the age of each child or sibling process.

So, what member or usage of `task_struct` would do this?

Comment: Did you look in the definition of `task_struct` for fields with names that contain 'time'?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried those and even using the supplied functions for comparison and subtraction I cannot seem to get anything relevant.  Specifically start_time.tv_sec

Comment: So right now I'm just picking the oldest child by the lowest pid located in the   list_head children    member for each process.  Will this suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use real_start_time or start_time in task_struct.
It is updated at the time of process creation

```
    struct timespec start_time;             /* monotonic time */
    struct timespec real_start_time;        /* boot based time */
```

Note: this is vanilla kernel no idea about android kernel

Comment: So, this is what I tried, the start_time.tvsec would always return 1.

Comment: Use this program to calculate start time of a process http://brokestream.com/procstat.html and also kernel source http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/array.c#L476.

Answer (score 2):

How about keeping things simple and looking ctime of /proc/PID/ for each process you are interested. Please notice that possible clock adjustments may make the ctime to look strange, and good program should not fail if elapsed time is negative due to such event.